# No value retrieved in the variable by the listener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Click here for my database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX7ln.jpg)I wanted to retrieve existing data of the child name in variable "name" before it gets updated.
So I was using a single event listener and wanted the "Quantity" to be retrieved into the variable "grab".
But when I display the value of grab through Toast it displays NULL.
 Please guide.

The code I'm using is :

```
mRootref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(name)) {

                            String grab =(String) dataSnapshot.child(name).child("Quality").getValue();
                            Toast.makeText(Database.this, grab, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Please the correct database strcuture and more code.

Comment: Thanks A lot @Alex Mamo

Answer (score 0):

Your child is named `Quantity`, not `Quality`.

You should replace this line`dataSnapshot.child(name).child("Quantity").getValue();`

Comment: thanks a lot. I was a fool posting this. I corrected as you said and its working. @Juan Cruz Soler